# Can we Host manifest.Json on other domain?

Tags: javascript, html, json, blogger

In Blogger, I try To Add Manifest.Json hosted on some other domain. But I'll get a warning in Start_URl.
here My Code:
`<link rel='Manifest' href='https://cdn.rawgit.com/ajaymalik14/Js/85c6a386/manifest.json'/>`
Is it Safe to Host Manifest.Json on Other Domain

Answer (score 2):

You can host the file on another domain, but the server needs to enable [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). From the [specification](https://w3c.github.io/manifest/#content-security-policy):

> Remote origins (e.g., a CDN) wanting to host manifests for various web applications will need to include the appropriate CORS response header in their HTTP response (e.g., `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com`).

It looks like `rawgit.com` automatically sends `Access-control-allow-origin: *`, so you shouldn't need to do anything special.

Comment: As i Host My manifest on Github, how can I add acess-control-allow-origin in that

Comment: I'm not sure if you can.

Comment: please tell me how To do that

Comment: I said I don't think you can. You need to use a web hosting service that you have more control over.

Comment: I don't think you need to do anything, rawgit.com enables CORS.

Comment: what about google firebase? I can Host a Website and script there

Comment: I don't know. You can try it and check the response headers in the Network tab of Developer Tools. Or use `curl` to display the response headers.